# How to estimate Azure Event Grid cost using Azure metrics

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-cost-calculation

I'm trying to build a cost model for my distributed system where Event Grid is a key piece.

Event Grid cost is based on millions of operations (`0.561€` per million). See [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-grid/?cdn=disable).

This is the cost of my Event Grid on one production environment for one month:
[image: Event Grid actual cost]

These are the metrics for the same month:
[image]

`Published Events + Delivered Events = 67.93M`

`67.93M * 0.561€ = 38.10€`

This is ~3.5 less times than the actual cost. I have run same exercise on other environments with less workload and the result is pretty similar, between 3 and 4 times less than the actual cost.

Does anyone know what am I missing to estimate correctly the cost of my Event Grid instance?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number you have is the actual number of events.

Then there maybe 3 (at least) reasons that you are being billed for more:

- Are the events being delivered to multiple endpoints. You pay per delivery.
- Have some of your systems had an outage? You pay for retry events.
- Are your events larger than 64KB. For each message you pay per 64KB increment.

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-grid/?cdn=disable

Comment: - Yes, most of the events are sent to at least 3 endpoints. But I guess that's already taken into the consideration on the metrics since the `Delivered` are almost three times the `Published`. So `Deliveries` are being taken into consideration on this cost calculations.
- Some services might have a low outage but not that high to increase the cost 3 times.
- No, I apply claim-check pattern so every event is lower than 64KB.

Comment: How is your filtering set up can an event be checked against several filters before it is matched?

Comment: No advanced filtering, just filtering by the subject `suffix`. Btw, I'm using Cloud Event Schema, but I don't think it affects.